# I got an error while trying to publish my Android app that read: "You told us your app doesn't comply with the Location permissions policy"

Tags: google-people-api

[image][image]

[image]

[google-people] I have an Android app that I recently published to the play store. I got an error while trying to publish the app that read: "You told us your app doesn't comply with the Location permissions policy".  I am not sure what this means, but here is some context about my situation.

My app, the one I tried to publish is a flavor of another app. So, I have a Main app and a copy of Main(the flavor app). The copy contains all the features and functionalities of the Main app, with modifications to the colors and assets of the app. For this copy(flavor app) I did not require background location so I removed it from it's manifest. I did not remove it from Main's manifest. Just the copy(flavor app). So, Main app's manifest has the the background location permission enabled, but the copy(flavor app) does not.

Is it because my flavor app does not have the background location permission enabled? According to the developers page:
"Manifest files that were part of the build but did not contribute elements or attributes are listed under Other Manifest Files on the right." So, although Main's manifest gets merged into the flavors, it does not contribute elements or attributes to the final apk buid of the flavor.

I would highly appreciate some clarification and understanding to this issue.

Please see attached image or go to: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#implicit_system_permissions?

[image: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#implicit_system_permissions]

Answer (score 1):

According to the Requesting access to background location, Google Play requires a strict(er) set of requirements to be able to use background permissions for apps installed via the Google Play store. It provides a set of guidelines which have to be fulfilled to allow an app to enter- or remain in the store with said permissions.

In short you have to follow the steps given below at Google support to verify your apps location permission requirement.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102?hl=en#zippy=